# Appending a character at the end of line for a match

Tags: linux, replace, suse

I have a bunch of files with lines like 'cycles=1000', 'cycles=1500' and so on (the number after the `=` varies from file to file).

My requirement is: I need to add a trailing zero only in these lines of the file.

There are other lines in the file that I want left untouched.

Can somebody help me with this?

-Giri

Comment: What system (Windows/Linux/other)?

Comment: What programming language are you using? What have you tried so far? Your question is not answerable as it is right now. You need to edit it and be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use sed command:

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/cycles=[0-9]*/&0/g'
```

EDIT:
If needed, you can add those line begin and end matching stuff to the command:

```
cat koe.txt | sed 's/^cycles=[0-9]*$/&0/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on an environment with decent text processing tools (like UNIX, Linux or Windows with CygWin), you can use `awk` to do this, as per the following transcript:

```
pax$ echo 'cycles=1000
notcycles=25
cycles=1500
something else again' | awk '/^cycles=/ {$0 = $0 "0"} {print}'

cycles=10000
notcycles=25
cycles=15000
something else again
```

Basically, any lines that start with the text `cycles=` have a `0` appended to them.

Then the line (modified or not) is output.

Comment: Sorry for the vague info.  I am in linux ( suse ) and can use awk.  I will try this and let u know

Comment: @user976474, I've updated the tags to make your question more targetd.